# Create a minimalistic grid/table showing interaction between two things

Tags: tables, grids, cell

Is there a way to create the following minimalistic-looking grid/table?

[image]

- The grid should have thick lines.
- The cells should be write-able.
- There should be a label denoting the name of the "player"

Some modification to

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|ccc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Colin}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&  & A  & B \\\cline{2-4}
    \multirow{3}*{Rose}  & A & $1$ & $-5$ \\
    & B & $-2$ & $4$ \\
    & C & $0$ & $3$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any news? Does received answer not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
                         
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Rose}
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Colin}\\
                    &       &   A   &   B   \\
        \cline{2-4}
    \multirow{3.8}*{\rothead{Rose}}  
                    &   A   & $ 1$  & $-5$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
                    &   B   & $-2$  & $ 4$ \\
        \cline{2-4}
                    &   C   & $ 0$  & $ 3$ \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

[image]

where table specification is

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|w{c}{12mm}|w{c}{12mm}}
```

Comment: For sure this question is duplicate, however it was more simple to write an answer than find duplicate on site.